# How can I redirect my subdomain from http to https using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have created a subdomain on a website I'm developing and I want it to redirect to https automatically, particularly since if I try to access it by typing http://test.example.com, it doesn't work - it just appears to be waiting for a response from the server for a while (maybe 30 secs) before eventually resolving to https://www.test.example.com (is this a clue to the problem..?)
I've tried adding a rule to catch all subdomains, in the .htaccess **in the root of the website**, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

(...but to no avail)

I've also tried a whole variety of other methods, in the htaccess file located in the **home directory of the subdomain**, as follows (one at a time of course):

```
#Method 1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

#Method 2
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Method 3
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =test.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

#Method 4
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]

#Method 5
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [nc]
```

None of these redirect the http://test.example.com subdomain to https - they do nothing except Method 2 which returns a 'too many redirects' error.
What am I missing here.?
Thank you

Comment: Are you using a CMS for this? The endless redirect reminds me of the situation in WordPress where a .htaccess rule was redirecting the site but the address in the db was redirecting it back. Could be a similar situation.

Comment: No, I'm not using any CMS..